# how to make email app in Android?

Tags: android

today I'm working with network in Android.I want to get mail from Gmail/Yahoo account and show them in textbox.Can anyone teach me how to fetch mail content ? I need a point to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **javamail – android jar** files to get and send email from android. From following you can also find a example to send email using android. This work is based on the opensourced version of JavaMail and activation (JAF) available in the glassfish repository, and some parts of Apache. You can find these files to download from this link https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list.

For Receiving email you can use following link. this link will be helpful for you http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-receiving-email-using-java-mail-api

Comment: You have been very helpful.Hope the javamail is safe :)